# Operating region for NMOS transistor - Can someone check my work?

Tags: transistors, mosfet, nmos

Given: Vtn = 0.4V
[image]

NMOS1
Vgs = Vg - Vs = 1.9V
Vgd = Vg - Vd = -0.6V
Vgd < Vtn and Vgs > Vtn
My answer is **Saturation Region**

NMOS2
Vgs = Vg - Vs = 2.2 - (-2.3) = 4.5V
Vgd = 2.2 - 0.5 = 1.7V
Vgd > Vtn and Vgs > Vtn
My answer is **Triode/Linear/Ohmic region**

NMOS3
Vgs = 0.9 - (-2.5) = 3.4V
Vgd = 0.9-0.5 = 0.4V
What region is the NMOS operating in if Vgd is equal to Vtn?

I have attempted to answer 1 and 2 as highlighted above but am unsure. As for number 3, my book only has cases for Vgd>Vtn and Vgd

Comment: Welcome to the site. Unfortunately for you, this is not a free design house, homework-writing service or an on-line technical encyclopedia, copied out to you on demand. People will help you take the next step if your questions shows that you've done as much as you possibly could on your own - which your post doesn't, I'm afraid. Please either revise your question showing your work and findings so far or delete it if you find Internet searches give you your answer anyway. Again, welcome.

Comment: @TonyM I already answered 1 and 2, and would just like to know if I did it right. As for number 3, my book only has cases for Vgd>Vtn and Vgd<Vtn, not if Vgd=Vtn

Comment: My mistake: I should have written "this is not a homework-checking service". VTC.

Comment: We are not here to do your homework for you.

Comment: I'm confused. Aren't we only closing homework question **with no attempted solution**?

Comment: Can you tell us about what you think might not be right?